# Angular inline CSS

Tags: angularjs, directive

How can I create a directive which gives me access to the $scope object in a inline style tag?

What I need is something like so:

```
<style>
    p { 
        font-size: {{userSetting.fontSize}} 
        margin: {{userSetting.margin}}
    }
</style>
```

I have started working on a directive for it, but can't figure out how to create it.

Comment: seems like you are looking in the wrong direction, you can manipulate the DOM but not the css classes, you should thin in terms of adding and removing classes to an element in the DOM

Comment: The inline styles are custom and up to the user though, so it could be margin: 10px or margin: 55px - that's up to the user. That's why I need to have them inline and not in classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... While i don't think it is a good idea to do this. You could accomplish it with a directive:

````
<ng-style-definition>
  h1 {
    color: {{h1.color}};
  }
</ng-style-definition>```

app.directive('ngStyleDefinition', function($timeout){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<style ng-transclude></style>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr){
      $timeout(function(){
        element.html(element.children().text())
      }, 0)
    }
  }
})
````

You could get a little cleaner bringing in the $parse or $interpolate services, but thats the gist of it.

A couple examples can be seen here: http://plnkr.co/edit/eqmFho55YckE5wmYHdJB?p=preview

Comment: Thanks - I'll mark this as the correct answer as it leads me to the right path. Why isn't it a good idea though? The logic behind it is that the user gets to style their own page, and I'm using inline styles to achieve it. I figured that would be faster than to style on the elements themselves with for instance ngStyle

Comment: I guess it really depends on the context of your application.